# How to update an already existing array by accessing it by a variable with the exact same name assigned to it

Tags: python, arrays, string

i declared an array earlier on in the program and then assigned a variable to the exact same array name .
I later on attempted to change a value within the array using the variable name i declared but the array is not updating.

```
 J2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] #i defined the array J2.
appointment = 'J2' # then i declared the variable appointment to the string J2
time = 3 # and i assigned the variable time=3. 
appointment[time] = 6 #i tried to input 6 into the J2 at index 3 by typing appointment[time]=6
```

But when
and then printing the array J2, i keep on getting an unchanged array`

Comment: Please post an actual python script that we can run. No need to comment the obvious stuff. If this was python it would fail because appointment is an immutable string. And even if it wasn't, the index is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: `appointment = 'J2'` You're assigning a string value.  This is NOT the `J2` array.  If you put a variable name in a string, it is just a string.

Comment: Conceptually, I believe they are looking to do `globals()[appointment][time] = 6` but the post I linked has some better alterative strategies.

Comment: Why can't you just assign `appointment = J2` directly?

Answer (score -1):

when you use a string to refer to a variable name, it doesn't directly access the variable itself. Instead, you can achieve this using a dictionary to store your arrays with their corresponding names.

Try this:

Solution 1:

```
J2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
arrays = {'J2': J2}
appointment = 'J2'

# Assign the variable time=3
time = 3

# Update the value in the array using the dictionary
arrays[appointment][time] = 6

print(arrays['J2'])
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Solution 2 (*as per suggested in comment*):

```
J2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

appointment = 'J2'

time = 3

# Update the value in the array using globals()
globals()[appointment][time] = 6

print(J2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```